# Flask Jinja2 HTML/CSS collapsible section buttons being places next to each other instead of below?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dynamic list of collapsible buttons with jinja2 from a list and using the guide here for the CSS button https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

Now when I change the width to 35% from 100% it does not put each button below another, it puts them side-by-side for some reason as shown in the picture below. Also, How would I be able to center this with CSS?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdhCj.jpg

When I try to center it the code will only render one of the collapsible buttons and not the number that is in the list?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 35%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    &#x200B;
    &#x200B;
    .active,
    .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    
    &#x200B;
    .collapsible:after {
      content: '\\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    &#x200B;
    .active:after {
      content: "\\2212";
    }
    
    &#x200B;
    &#x200B;
    &#x200B;
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      width: 35%;
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    &#x200B;
    &#x200B;
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <h2>Collapsibles</h2>


  <p>A Collapsible:</p>

  {% for item in test_list %}
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">

    <p> {{ item }}</p>

  </div>

  {% endfor %}


  <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

    var i;

    &#x200B;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {

      coll\[i\].addEventListener("click", function() {

        this.classList.toggle("active");

        var content = this.nextElementSibling;

        if (content.style.display === "block") {

          content.style.display = "none";

        } else {

          content.style.display = "block";

        }

      });

    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `button` default display is `display: inline-block`.

So this why the 2 button are coming next to each other.

Only change display to `display: block;` for example and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now how can I center it? When I do a dynamic number of buttons with Jinja2 from a list it only renders one of the buttons, and shows the last button generated from the list. It looks like this when I try to center it; https://imgur.com/a/83K9ZLF

Comment: You mean like center the picto? Did you try `text-align: center;` ?